# .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working with mongoose.

I wrote the following code in routes.js

```
var docs = require('../app/controllers/genericController');
    app.post('/newdoc', docs.createMainDoc);
    app.get('/listdoc', docs.listDocs);
```

and in genericController :

```
exports.listDoc = function(req, res) {
    var Model = mongoose.model(req.model); //i dont know, if this is defined or undefined. Actually i am not able to check it. Even if i comment whole body of this exports.listDoc, then also i get the same error. just assume here that here i am getting model.
    Model.find(function(err, models) {
        if (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                status: 500
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(models);
        }
    });
};
```

Bu i am getting error :

```
.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Means that `docs.listDocs` is undefined...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have `docs.listDocs` instead of `docs.listDoc`. That's why it's `undefined`.

```
app.get('/listdoc', docs.listDoc/*s*/);
```