# NodeJS : app.get() does not operate as I exected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJS and here is my routes/recom.js which is now doing a lot of logics stuffs. I will move the logics to somewhere else later. But now I need to solve the error first.

```
exports.scrape = function(req, res) {

  var APIURI = 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/abbxqyg4?apikey=6IrCGNcorodTBSfNawS6sZkHw3LeZVIN';
  var receivedJason; 
  res.type('text/plain');     
  request({
    url: APIURI,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log('API Retrieved Successfully!');
    res.json(body);
    receivedJason = JSON.stringify(body);

    var node = db.createNode({hello: 'world'});     // instantaneous, but...
    node.save(function (err, node) {    // ...this is what actually persists.
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error saving new node to database:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Node saved to database with id:', node.id);
      }
    });

   }
  });          
};
```

And this is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var recom = require('./server/routes/recom.js');

var app = express();

app.get('/', recom.scrape);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2019);
```

and I got the following error:

> Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You did of course try to put the function directly in the route to see what happens?

Comment: adeno, actually, I don't know the proper place for declaring this function. (In "app.js" in "route" or in "model" or "non of them") I know that I need to just mention the name of the function. So would you please explain me about the right way of doing that.

Comment: I was thinking maybe you should try it like this and see what happens -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mg5udp5v/1/**

Comment: I moved the code into the controller folder after seeing [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616074/get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined?rq=1 and now the logic is in controller and I think it is the right way. so now I have simple app.get() in my routes.js.

Comment: After moving logic to controllers folder of NodeJS. I encountered another problem: I have these in my routes.js: app.get('/', controller.scrape); and app.get('/save, controller.save). The first one works well while I enter "localhost" but when I enter localhost/save the browser shoots me the error: "Cannot GET /save"

Comment: I expect that entering localhost/save in browser. save a dummy node in the database. But its not done. Also I tried app.post() instead of apt.get(). But no success. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be in the export. In `routes/recom.js` use:

```
module.exports.scrape = function(req, res) { //...
```

The reason you get an `[object Undefined]` is that `exports` is not the same object as `module.exports`, and thus the item looked for does not exist.

In addition, in app.js you may need to use one of:

```
var recom = require('routes/recom.js');
// or:
var recom = require('server/routes/recom.js');
```

Depending on you full structure.